# Projections over sub collections - EF4

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-expressions

Lets assume the following model with EF4:

```
class Order
{
   ....
   public int Id {get;private set;}

   //ICollection is the root of all evil here
   public ICollection<OrderDetail> Details {get;private set;}
}
```

I can then project over this structure with Linq:

```
var IdAndCount = context
  .Orders
  .Select ( o => new {
           Id = o.Id,
           Count = o.Details.Where(d => d.Foo > 0).Count()});
```

So far so good, this will be fully translated to sql.

Now to the problem, what if I want to extract the where clause predicate in this query:

```
Func<OrderDetail,bool> detailPredicate = d => d.Foo > 0;

var IdAndCount = context
    .Orders
    .Select ( o => new {
         Id = o.Id,
         Count = o.Details
                  .Where(detailPredicate)
                  .Count()});
```

This compiles, but fails at runtime because there is no way for EF4 to translate the predicate to SQL since it is a Func and not an Expression.

Changing the predicate to an `Expression<Func<OrderDetail,bool>>` will not work since ".Where" on the OrderDetails links to the IEnumerable "Where" since the details are ICollection.

So, is it possible to extract parts of a bigger Linq query if the properties beeing traversed are IEnumerable or similair?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Expression<Func<OrderDetail,bool>> detailPredicate = d => d.Foo > 0;
```

Comment: This will not work since OrderDetails is an ICollection and the where clause on ICollection uses Func and not Expression<Func.